# What's new in IE8 regarding to WebBrowser Control?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer-8, browser, webbrowser-control

What's new in IE8 regarding to WebBrowser Control *via interfaces or direct API calls*? Is there any new extensibility feature or a new API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that there has not be a new .NET release, I don't expect any direct change to the API.

There may still be enancements to some of the interfaces already exposed.